# Does object instantiation have to occur inside a using block expression?

Tags: c#, io

I was wondering if there is a difference between this code:

```
// style 1
using (Stream stream_dst = File.Create("output.txt"))
using (Stream stream_src = File.OpenRead("input.txt"))
{
    stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
}
```

And the following code where the objects are opened outside:

```
// style 2
Stream stream_output = File.Create("output.txt");
Stream stream_input  = File.OpenRead("input.txt");

using (Stream stream_dst = stream_output)
using (Stream stream_src = stream_input)
{
    stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
}
```

Does the object being handled inside the `using(...)` context also have to be instantiated in the `using(...)` expression, or can it be instantiated anywhere and still be properly handled and closed at the end?

**Remark:** This is a pedagogical question, not about whether someone should do something, but whether they can. Specifically, if there are any differences between the two methods. Please keep this in mind.

Comment: The first approach is considered better because you will not be able to use those variables, even if you attempted by mistake. But you can use the second approach

Comment: Why the secondary variable? The second can be reduced to `using (stream_output) { ... }`. Instantiation does not *have* to occur in the using statement, but it should.

Comment: What would be the point of instantiating the variables separately?  If you use option 2, when execution leaves the `using` block, the objects will be disposed and will no longer be usable elsewhere.

Comment: Option 2 is acceptable but if the variable is only ever created to be then be passed into a `using` statement then it's a waste of memory ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @James Can you clarify where additional memory will be used by Option 2, and how much of it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Option 2 creates an additional variable to store a copy of the `Stream` reference - been a while since I've lived in the .NET world but IIRC it would be around 4 bytes for a ref.

Comment: @James That's not really "wasting memory", especially since it's going right back out of scope. It's lost in the noise.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you can be sarcastic about it all you like, and I completely understand that it's a micro-optimization....but the fact still stands, why waste 4 bytes when you don't have to? Why write more code when you don't have to?

Comment: @EdPlunkett that's your interpretation, I used it as just another example of why option 2 isn't recommended - you seem to be making a debate out of nothing here given we're both singing off the same hymn sheet - option 1 is recommended for various reasons. Also, you seem to be implying that it's a bad thing to make developers (new or old) aware of how they are allocating memory, to that point I'd disagree with you :)

Comment: @James The JIT would be entirely within its rights to reuse any memory allocated for the locals stream_output and stream_input, so its not clear to me that there is even a functional difference in the amount of memory used in this example.

Comment: Indeed - the semantic difference in whether the first stream is disposed of if the second stream can't be created is *much, much* more important than the space taken for a local variable.

Comment: @JonSkeet completely agree, I'm not debating that at all, nor am I trying to debate which reason is more prominant than the other - if anything I was merely trying to give _another_ example of why option 1 is preferrable. But it's embroiled into a debate about a completely minor / passing comment, a stark reminder of why I stopped contributing on the .NET threads.

Comment: @MikeZboray so how does it reuse memory for variables are aren't yet deallocated?

Comment: @James The JIT is free to notice that it can simply reuse the same storage for the new variables. There is no requirement that because you declared a named temporary that there is stack space allocated for it.

Comment: @MikeZboray that just doesn't sound right to me, if a ref var is comparable to a key to a house, how can I give you a copy of the key and someone else if they are mutually exclusive? How does that work if I pass one of those references into a function? You are suggesting if I defined 10 ref vars (all pointing to the same reference) that would only allocate 4 bytes and not 10^4? Do you have any collateral that explains how that works? I'm intrigued.

Comment: @James To stretch the analogy a bit, you are not making a copy of the key at all. You are telling Alice to make a copies of a key so that she can give it to Bob. Well suppose Bob never shows up, maybe Alice knows this and decides to not make a copy because that's extra work. That's what the JIT is doing. I don't have a spec for you but this is kind of optimization is mentioned frequently in various [articles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/) and [discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1993).

Comment: @MikeZboray I'm fully aware of the JITs job, and nothing in the links you've provided _guarantee_ that the variable would be optimized (particularly given they're named differently). Regardless, I think the point I was making has been lost in the ether here, just because the JIT _may_ clean up after you it's still good to understand the implications of the code you write, particularly when it's unnecessary. When you work on embedded systems long enough you learn to appreciate the importance of 4 bytes...

Comment: @James Oh I didn't mean to suggest that it *must* do this optimization, just that it would be valid and likely. This might be different in C or C++. FWIW I agree with you that the line of thinking that "its only four bytes so what does it matter?" Is not particularly useful because in some contexts these details do matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
using (Stream stream_dst = File.Create("output.txt"))
using (Stream stream_src = File.OpenRead("input.txt"))
{
    stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
}
```

is the same as this:

```
using (Stream stream_dst = File.Create("output.txt"))
{
    using (Stream stream_src = File.OpenRead("input.txt"))
    {
        stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
    }
}
```

Both ensure that if an object is created it will also get disposed.

In this case:

```
Stream stream_output = File.Create("output.txt");
Stream stream_input  = File.OpenRead("input.txt");

using (Stream stream_dst = stream_output)
using (Stream stream_src = stream_input)
{
    stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
}
```

`stream_output` will get disposed because you're disposing `stream_dst`, and it's the same stream. But if an exception is thrown before that `using` block then `stream_output` will not get disposed.

A `using` block allows us to combine creating/acquiring an object with ensuring its disposal. If the `using` block follows creating/acquiring the object then it will still dispose it, but only if no exception is thrown before the `using` statement is executed. We wouldn't generally separate the two because combining them is the benefit of `using`.

Answer (score 4):

In the second example, the object will not be disposed correctly if an exception occurs after `File.Create` but before the corresponding `using` statement. In this code, an obvious possibility would be `File.OpenRead` throwing an exception because "input.txt" wasn't found.

Guaranteeing that the `Dispose` method is called even if exceptions occur is the biggest advantage of a `using` statement over simply calling `Dispose()` at the end of the method. Separating the object creation from the `using` block has a high chance of breaking that guarantee.

Additionally, as others have noted, instantiating the disposable object inside the `using` statement as in the first example limits the variable scope so that the object can't be accessed after being disposed. It's also simply shorter and cleaner, at least in these examples.

Answer (score 1):

Technically they are different however it is minor.

The point of a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) is to ensure disposal of managed types that access un-managed resources.

**STYLE 1:**

Declaring and initializing within a `using` statement (block) ensures that `.Dispose()` is called on the `IDisposable` objects declared and initialized within it. Even if an exception occurs. This approach prevents access to these objects from outside the scope of the `using` block.

```
// *** Declaration and Instantiation within using statement ***
// *** prevents access to these variables outside of the scope ***
// *** of the using statement. ***
using (Stream stream_dst = File.Create("output.txt"))
    using (Stream stream_src = File.OpenRead("input.txt"))
    {
        stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
    }
```

**STYLE 2:**

Declaring and initializing outside of a `using` statement (block) and them declaring and initializing objects based on them inside of a `using` block will still allow the initial objects to be disposed of properly, however if an exception were to occur before the `using` block the objects will not be disposed of by the `using` block. It also allows you to reference the potentially disposed objects after you have used them in the `using` block, which could cause you headaches in the future. If that happens you'll probably see an exception message relating to `accessing a disposed closure`.

```
Stream stream_output = File.Create("output.txt");
Stream stream_input  = File.OpenRead("input.txt");

using (Stream stream_dst = stream_output)
    using (Stream stream_src = stream_input)
    {
        stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
    }
```

From the microsoft docs about using style 2:

You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the `using` statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case, after control leaves the `using` block, the object remains in scope but probably has no access to its unmanaged resources. In other words, it's not fully initialized anymore. If you try to use the object outside the `using` block, you risk causing an exception to be thrown. For this reason, it's generally better to instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to the using block.

Interesting to note:

According to the docs you can declare multiple instances of a type in a using statement. What I take from this is you should be able to do the using statement declaration like so:

```
using (Stream stream_dst = File.Create("output.txt"), Stream stream_src = File.OpenRead("input.txt"))
{
    stream_src.CopyTo(stream_dst);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, will the variables `stream_output` and `stream_input` become `null` in version 2 after the using statement finishes? Or will they just be "closed"?

Comment: @AlanSTACK Very good question. They will not be `null` unless you write code which explicitly sets them to null. This is probably the most important reason to avoid style 2: The references remain in scope after they're disposed. There's nothing to be gained by letting that happen, and it becomes possible for an inattentive programmer to try to use them after they've been disposed.

Comment: @AlanSTACK I've updated the answer to clarify that a little, and Ed Plunkett is correct, the objects are not set to null, but they also are not fully initialized anymore.

Comment: @NullReff I never knew about multiple comma-separated initializations in a using. That's handy. Thanks.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I honestly just found it when I was grabbing the docs link for this answer. I also think it's handy and honestly giddy to start using it.